# Firebase error: cannot acces zzans

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I develop an android app with use of Firebase. And when I want to build my project I get error in the `OnCreateView()` method on initializing, I get the error:

> Error:(69, 36) error: cannot access zzans
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzans not found

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener()
```

LoginActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private SignInButton signInButton;

    public static final int SIGN_IN_CODE = 777;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener firebaseAuthListener;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_DARK);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN_CODE);
            }
        });


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    goMainScreen();
                }
            }
        };

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(result.getSignInAccount());
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_log_in, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(signInAccount.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                signInButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.not_firebase_auth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void goMainScreen() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseAuthListener != null) {
            firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(firebaseAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kz.brainpull.googleauth"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Help me to solve that error, please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the most recent version of the Firebase API (10.2.1).

I tested your gradle and managed to replicate the error, but after updating the dependency for Firebase Auth to:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
```

It worked properly. I suggest updating the other Firebase dependencies to avoid other errors similar to this.